# Subtract One Category from Another by Quarter in R

Tags: r

I want to subtract sales for each category by quarter (only for one year) with the first quarter subtracted from 10

```
        Qtr    Category         Value 
202001      1             10    
202002      1             40    
202003      1             100    
202004      1             20     
202001      2             80    
202002      2             90    
202003      2             4    
202004      2             7    
201901      1             8
201902      1             9
201903      1             20
20194       1             30
```

Results:

```
        Qtr    Name         Value 
202001      1             0    
202002      1             30    
202003      1             60    
202004      1             -80    
202001      2             70    
202002      2             10    
202003      2             -86    
202004      2             3    
201901      1             -2
201902      1             1
201903      1             11
20194       1             10
```

Comment: Could you verify the result you expect? for example why do your substract 40 from third line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution with `ave`.

```
with(df1, ave(Value, Category, FUN = function(x){c(x[1] - 10, diff(x))}))
# [1]   0  30  60 -80  70  10 -86   3 -12   1  11  10
```

Then, assign this result to the appropriate data set column.

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
        Qtr    Category         Value 
202001      1             10    
202002      1             40    
202003      1             100    
202004      1             20     
202001      2             80    
202002      2             90    
202003      2             4    
202004      2             7    
201901      1             8
201902      1             9
201903      1             20
201904       1             30
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using the tidyverse. To start, I import your data that I saved in fa.txt, correct the last value in the Quarter column, and convert the Value column from integer to numeric.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table("fa.txt", header = TRUE)

df[df$Qtr == 20194, "Qtr"] <- 201904
df$Value <- as.numeric(df$Value)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(interm = str_replace(Qtr, "(\\d{2})$", ".\\1")) %>%
  separate(interm, c("Year", "Quarter"), "\\.") %>%
  group_by(Year, Category) %>%
  mutate(New_Value = if_else(Quarter == "01", Value - 10, Value - lag(Value)))
```

Comment: Upvote but I don't think you need to convert the Value column from integer to numeric. R will take care of that if decimals are ever to show up.

Comment: I thought so, but whenever I use the if_else function I get an error message telling me I need to convert to numeric.

Comment: That's because `if_else` is more strick than `ifelse`. I missed that point. But in this case i would still not coerce to numeric and use `ifelse`, the speed gain of `if_else` is a small one.